# How do you allocate memory for an linked list when passing its reference instead of its pointer?

Tags: c++, reference

How do you allocate memory for an link list when passing its reference instead of its pointer?

For example:

```
struct node {
  string info;
  node *next;

};

void add(node &aNode){


//if I use
node *newNode;
newNode = new node;
aNode.next = newNode; //aNode.next = newNode; doesn't work either

//allocating on heap seems to give segmentation error.


}


int main() {                                                        

  node *aNode;
  aNode = new node;
  add (aNode);


}

Compiler error: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘node&’ from expr
```

alternatively if I use

```
int main() {                                                        

  node aNode;
  add (aNode);
  add (aNode);
  aNode.next->next->info = "abc";
  string a = aNode.next->next->info;


}
```

This give segmentation fault.

So is it possible to allocate for an linked list just with its reference? (this is C++)

Comment: -1: Please at least attempt to provide some compilable C++!  Your function argument has no type, and `node newNode; newNode = new node;` is not going to work, as `newNode` is not a pointer...

Comment: I have already edited it before you typed your comment

Comment: What's the question now? Oh, wait, your `add` signature is still bogus.

Comment: The final `aNode.next = &anotherNode;` is grammatically OK, but it will leave `aNode` with a dangling pointer to a destroyed object. You **have** to `new` up a node to make it "permanent".

Comment: Sorry this is meant as an example not compilable. It was just to show what I used. In the real code I don't have the second //if I use...

Comment: @Mark: So what's the ultimate question or problem?

Comment: @Mark: If you're asking a question about (or closely related to) syntax, it's imperative that your question includes your *actual* code.  Otherwise, we all end up arguing about irrelevancies, because it's difficult to see what the *actual* issue is..

Comment: @Mark: I can't see any reason why your second example should give a seg-fault.  And indeed, I tried compiling and running it, and saw no problem...

Comment: @Mark: Agreed with Oli, post the whole shebang. Your second version, calling `add` on a stack variable, works fine with me. No telling what's actually going on on your end.

Comment: @Mark: Also, you seem to be generally confused by the notions of pointers and references (otherwise you'd notice that your first `main` version calls `add` with the wrong type). Perhaps you should consult a good general introduction to C++?

Comment: It does compile but when I try to use the node it gives seg fault. For example: string a = anode.next->next->info.

Comment: @Mark: Then add *that* line to your code snippet!  How can we diagnose the problem if you don't give us the code that causes the problem?

Comment: sorry Oli I have done what you asked if there is anymore problem please tell me.

Comment: @Mark: No worries.  It is now possible to answer your question.

Comment: @Mark: You continue changing the question and the code. Of course your new thing will break because you're just overwriting the `next` element of the root node, rather than moving on to the next child node. Your node datastructure doesn't track the end and you're not writing iteratively.

Comment: @Oli I missed a line when I pasted.

Comment: Use std::list. Why do you reinvent wheel? :-)

Comment: @George: Every programmer should implement a linked-list at least once in their lifetime.  Until they've gone through the pain of understanding pointers, they're not a real programmer!

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth, I agree with you. But one thing is writing production software and another is learning basics (such as implementing linked list first time in life :-))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second variant of `main()`, you are calling `add(aNode)` twice.  But you're providing it the same parameter each time.  So although you're creating two new `node` objects, one of them is lost forever (a *memory leak*).  And `aNode.next` ends up pointing to the other one.  `aNode.next->next` is not a valid pointer, hence the seg-fault when you try to access something through it.

Depending on what you want to achieve, you could try this:

```
node aNode;
add(aNode);        // Basically does: aNode.next = new node;
add(*aNode.next);  // Basically does: aNode.next->next = new node;
```

There are better ways of doing linked-lists, but this would at least avoid the seg-fault.

Comment: Hmm I seem to be misunderstanding reference. Because when I looked at the void swap(x, y) example the original variable x and y are changed. So shouldn't aNode be changed after the first call?

Comment: @Mark: Yes, in your code, `aNode` will be changed after the first call.  Specifically, `aNode.next` will now point at a valid `node` object.  But after the second call, `aNode` will be changed again.  Specifically, `aNode.next` will now point at a *different* valid `node` object.

Comment: Just a side question, is aNode store on stack? and is the node its pointing to stored on heap? If it's true then does that mean it's ok to use stack and heap together?

Comment: @Mark: Yes, it's totally fine to use stack and heap together.  It's all just memory.  What you need to be careful of is accidentally invoking `delete` on a stack-based variable (more specifically, on a variable with "automatic" or "static" storage duration).  Equally, you must always remember to invoke `delete` on a heap-based variable at some point.

Answer (score 3):

It should be

```
node * newNode = new node;
aNode.next = newNode
```

You have to take care of deletion manually, e.g. check if `aNode.next` isn't already occupied (and delete if it is).

Further, the `add` function signature should read:

```
void add(node & aNode) { ... }
```

By the way, the STL comes with a nice `<forward_list>` ;-)

---

It's hard to tell what you're actually asking, but going by the question title perhaps you have in mind a node structure like this:

```
struct Node {
  Node & next;
  /* payload data */
  Node(Node & n) : next(n) /* ... */ { }
};
```

Such a node would store its successor "by reference"; but you would have to initialize it with an existing node! (There is no such thing as a "null" reference.) By the [Poultry-Oval Impasse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicken_or_the_egg), you cannot do this.

---

Alright, while you continue to refuse to post your full code, here is my almost literal copy/paste of your code which works fine with me:

**Update:** I'm adding a feature to add a node at the end, which you might want.

```
#include <string>

struct node {
  std::string info;
  node *next;
  node(std::string i = "") : info(i), next(NULL) { }
};

void add(node &aNode)
{
  node *newNode;
  newNode = new node;
  aNode.next = newNode;
}

void add_at_end(node &aNode, std::string value = "")
{
  node *newNode, *n = &aNode;
  while (n->next) n = n->next; // move to the end

  newNode = new node(value);
  n->next = newNode;
}

int main()
{
  node aNode, bNode;
  add(aNode);
  add_at_end(bNode, "Hello");
  add_at_end(bNode, "World");
  add_at_end(bNode, "!");
}
```

Compile with `g++ -o prog prog.cpp -W -Wall -pedantic`.

---

Finally, here's the STL way of achieving the same thing:

```
#include <forward_list>
#include <string>
int main() {
  std::forward_list<std::string> bList;
  bList.push_front("Hello");
  bList.push_front("World");
  bList.push_front("!");
}
```

Comment: I think my program is just incorrect syntactically. I have the address of the node I am passing through I don't see how I can't manipulate it to point to another node.

Comment: Just turn `add_at_end` into a method. It's C++ not C with `class` keyword ;-)

Comment: @Pawel: Hehe, I think we're way past questions of good style, eh? But check out my latest addition. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
int main() {                                                        

  node *aNode;
  aNode = new node;
  add (*aNode);
}
```

You have to pass reference to object, not a pointer.

I checked your code and I didn't get segmentation fault when allocating on stack: http://ideone.com/gTRIG.

---

My proposition:

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct node {
  string info;
  node *next;
  node(string str): info(str), next(NULL) {}
  ~node() { if(next != NULL) delete next; }
  node *add(string info){
    node *newNode = new node(info);
    return aNode.next = newNode;
  }
};

int main(){
  node rootNode("My rootnode");
  node *nxt = rootNode.add("Next node");
  nxt->add("Last node");
  // No need to call delete, because destructor will clear heap
}
```

Comment: -1 No reason why `add` can't work on a stack variable. (In fact it does work fine for me.)

Comment: OK, sorry, I see what you were trying to fix. Undone! (Oh, I cannot undo apparently "until you edit something". Woops.)